# Makefile, applying a function to a list

Tags: makefile

In a `Makefile`, I am trying to populate lists by transforming items from an initial list.

As in my real code, those transformations are non-trivial, I try to use a `define... endef` construct, to apply to each element of the initial list, containing the logic of what I want to accomplish. Then, I apply this "function" using a `foreach` containing a `eval` and `call`.

But something weird happens: it seems that the last element of the list is not treated by the "function".

Here is a MWE `Makefile`:

```
libraries :=

define Function
    libName = lib$(1)

    libraries += $(libName)
    # [...more things...]
endef

libs = a b c
$(foreach lib,$(libs),$(eval $(call Function,$(lib))))

all:
    $(foreach lib,$(libs),$(lib))
    @echo $(libraries)
```

And the result of running the command `make`:

```
a b c
liba libb
```

I expected the second line to have an extra item `libc` at its end...

What did I do wrong? What did I misunderstood?

Comment: As a general rule I think it is important to note that the programming constructs of make are much better used purely functional. The procedural sideways which are possible through `eval` quickly get you in troubles as you have seen. See also https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt for a number of helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the fact that the argument you provide is expanded *twice*: first by `call`, then again as part of the `eval`.

You can get a better idea of what is happening with `eval` by replacing it with `info`:

```
$(foreach lib,$(libs),$(info $(call Function,$(lib))))
```

This will show you the text that `eval` is evaluating.  You'll see that here:

```
libraries += $(libName)
```

`libName` is being evaluated by `call`, *before* `eval` sees it.  So it expands to the *previous* run's setting of `libName` (or the empty string in the first run).

You need to examine your `define` and for every variable that is a `call` parameter like `$(1)` you use it like this, so `call` expands it, and for every other variable or function reference you probably want to escape it with `$$` so that `call` doesn't expand it and it's left to `eval` to expand:

```
define Function
    libName = lib$(1)

    libraries += $$(libName)
    # [...more things...]
endef
```